# Ansible Task: with_dict statement got triggered, even if the when-clause should prevent this

Tags: ansible, munin

I'am trying to automate the creation of the smart_[diskdevice] links to

> /usr/share/munin/plugins/smart_

during the installation of the munin node via ansible.

The code here works partially, except there is no diskdevice to link on the target machine. Then I got a fatal failure with

> `{"msg": "with_dict expects a dict"}`

I've review the ansible documentation and tried to search the problem in the web. For my understanding, the whole "file" directive should not be executed if the "when"-statement fails.

```
---
- name: Install Munin Node
  any_errors_fatal: true
  block:
...

# drives config
    - file:
        src: /usr/share/munin/plugins/smart_
        dest: /etc/munin/plugins/smart_{{ item.key }}
        state: link
      with_dict: "{{ ansible_devices }}"
      when: "item.value.host.startswith('SATA')"
      notify:
        - restart munin-node
```

On targets with a SATA-Drive, the code works. Drives like "sda" are found and the links are created. Loop- and other soft-Devices are ignored (as intended)
Only on a Raspberry with no SATA-Drive at all i got the fatal failure.

Comment: What's in `ansible_devices`? Add `- debug: var=ansible_devices` before your "file" task.

Comment: very interesting: On my x86 targets, I got a tree-structure of the devices. But on the Raspi, I got all devices in one line. The line-wrap is missing.
The System is a *4.15.0-1041-raspi2 #44-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT aarch64 aarch64 aarch64 GNU/Linux*

Comment: If you think a comment adds value then you can up it. Others can see then whether the problem is potentially solved.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the `with_dict` option to set the `loop`. This sets the value of the `item` variable for each iteration as a dictionary with two keys:

1. `key`: The name of the current key in the `dict`.
2. `value`: The value of the existing key in the `dict`.

You are then running the `when` option that checks the `item` variable on each iteration. So check if that is the behavior you want.

Regarding your error, it is being thrown because for some reason, `ansible_devices` is not a `dict` as the error says. And Ansible checks for the validity of the `with_dict` type before resolving the `when` condition.

Check the following example:

```
---
- name: Diff test
  hosts: local
  connection: local
  gather_facts: no
  vars:
    dict:
      value: True
      name: "dict"
  tasks:
    - debug: var=item
      when: dict.value == False
      with_dict: '{{ dict }}'

    - debug: var=item
      when: dict.value == True
      with_dict: '{{ dict }}'

    - debug: var=item
      when: dict.value == False
      with_dict: "Not a dict"
```

The first two `task` will succeed because they have a valid `dict` on the `with_dict` option and a correct condition on the `when` option. The last one will fail because the `with_dict` value has the wrong type, even though the `when` condition resolves correctly and should guarantee to skip the `task`.

I hope it helps.